# Rails - call controller from javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Extreme rails nooby here.
I am trying to do a simple call to a controller from a javascript file and am fairly stuck, research says I need a ajax request. Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Here is my controller - It simply returns a boolean

```
class ReferredFriend < ActiveRecord::Base

def refer_email_exists(email)
/return a boolean
```

Here is my javascript - obviously incorrect syntax, but you get my general idea

```
if ReferredFriend.refer_email_exists(message.get('to_email')) == 'true'
  alert "That email already exists!"
```

the route to the controller is: app/models/referred_friend.rb

I put this in my routes file, however I'm guessing this is incorrect as well

```
resources :referred_friends do
  get :refer_email_exists
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The way to do want you want is make a ajax call to your route, something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<url route to refer_email_exists>",
  success: function(result){
  // check result then
  alert "That email already exists!"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about simple AJAX call?

```
$.ajax({
    url: Routes.test_email_path(email),
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function (data) {
    // handling success
}).fail(function (data) {
    // handling failure
}
```

Where Routes is from [js-routes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes) gem.

Answer (score 0):

Rails provides button shortcodes for remote actions like calling a Rails controller action VIA AJAX. From the Rails docs http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to

> `link_to` is a helper that assists with generating links. It has a `:remote` option you can use like this:
>
> `<%= link_to "an article", @article, remote: true %>`
>
> which generates:
>
> `<a href="/articles/1" data-remote="true">an article</a>`
>
> You can bind to the same Ajax events as form_for. Here's an example. Let's assume that we have a list of articles that can be deleted with just one click. We would generate some HTML like this:
>
> `<%= link_to "Delete article", @article, remote: true, method: :delete %>
>   and write some CoffeeScript like this:`
>
> `$ ->
>     $("a[data-remote]").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
>       alert "The article was deleted."`